# nginx rewrite & parameter full-url and file extensions

Tags: nginx

I will try to be brief. I have the following nginx rewrite url:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)?$ /index.php?completeURL=$1 last;
```

**I want a url like:**

```
http://mywebsite.com/http://www.otherwebsite.com/dir1/dirx/article.php&id=2&category=1
```

**request:**

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?completeURL=http://www.otherwebsite.com/dir1/dirx/article.php&id=2&category=1
```

Currently the nginx rule have a problem. **Example: If the parameter contains a `.php` extension he looks for that file on my server.**

Example: `http://mywebsite.com/dir1/dirx/article.php`

How can I solve this problem in your opinion?

---

**UPDATE:**
here the nginx configuration (and rewrite) files:

- *(config)* https://gist.github.com/ivanionut/cc53c9de372b932c3937d9394d3b448c
- *(rewrite)* https://gist.github.com/ivanionut/4df3ad9b858a54ae01461ab078adffb6

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (assuming that the server does nothing else other than serve `index.php`) is to remove the usual `location ~ \.php$` block and perform a `rewrite ... break;` in the same block as the `fastcgi_pass`. There are a number of ways of achieving this, including:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)?$ /index.php?completeURL=$1 break;
    fastcgi_pass ...
    ...
}
```

An alternative strategy is to perform the rewrite *only if* a local file does not already exist, but you need to ensure that `.php` files are tested too. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
    fastcgi_pass ...
    ...
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)?$ /index.php?completeURL=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: I tried your second solution, but I get this error:

`2016/04/26 22:21:05 [error] 10591#0: *1846 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while redirect to named location "@rewrites", client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: website.com, request: "GET /http://www.website.com/dfgdfgghgh.cfm HTTP/2.0", host: “website.com”`

Comment: It will loop if /index.php does not exist. Is 'root' defined correctly?

Comment: hi @Richard Smit. I updated my post. I have included the complete nginx configuration file. try to give us a look.

Comment: Could you look at the nginx rules I posted? You have at least one more suggestion for me? Thank you so much.